# What is a good open source C/C++ math library that supports vector math and complex numbers?

Tags: c++, math, vector, complex-numbers

I am working on a project that needs vector math and complex numbers.

I am looking a for a good open source API that supports C/C++ and hopefully has decent performance.

I can write these functions myself but it will be ugly and slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [C++ complex numbers library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/)
Also, Boost provides [linear Algebra package](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 6):

I regularly use Sony Vector Math library bundled with [bullet physics](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/). It's fast has many linear algebra algorithms.
For complex numbers you can simply use [std::complex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used any of these packages personally, but head over to [Object-Oriented Numerics](http://www.oonumerics.org/oon/) for a great selection of available libraries

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) is pretty much standard in research and should offer the stuff you need as well.