# How to optimize math with 2D vectors?

Tags: ios, math, vector

I’m working on iOS app that performs some calculations with an array of thousand objects. The objects have properties with x and y coordinates, velocity for x and y axises and couple other x-y properties. There is some math to calculate an interaction between physical objects represented by objects in the array. The math is pretty straight forward, basically it is calculation of the forces applied to the objects, speed and change in position (x,y) for each objects. I wrote a code using regular  scalar math in Objective C, it worked fine on iPhone 5s, however too slow on other devices like iPhone 4, 4s, 5 and iPad mini. I found that the most time consuming operations were the calculations of the distance between 2 points and calculations of the length of a vector like shown below which involves taking a square root:

```
float speed = sqrtf(self.dynamic.speed_x,2)+pow(self.dynamic.speed_y,2));
```

So, I had to do something to make the calculations quicker. I re-wrote the code to make the properties with the coordinates of the objects and such properties as velocity which were presented by X and Y components to be vectors of GLKVector2 type. I was hoping that it would make the calculations of the variables like the distance between 2 vectors (or points, as per my understanding), addition and subtraction of vectors significantly faster due to using special vector functions like GLKVector2Distance, GLKVector2Normalize,GLKVector2Add etc. However, it didn’t help too much in terms of performance, because, as I believe, to put the object with properties of GLKVector2 type to the array I had to use NSValue, as well as to decode the GLKVector2 values back from the object in the array to perform vector calculations. Below is the code from calculation method in object’s implementation:

```
GLKVector2 currentPosition;
[self.currentPosition getValue:&currentPosition];
GLKVector2 newPosition;


// calculations with vectors. Result is in newPosition.

self.currentPosition = [NSValue value:&newPosition withObjCType:@encode(GLKVector2)];
```

Moreover, when I rewrote the code to use GLKVector2, I got memory warnings and after some time of running the applications sometimes crashes.

I spend several days trying to find a better way to do the calculations faster, I looked at vecLib, openGL, but have not found a solution that would be understandable for me. I have a feeling that I might have to look at writing code in C and integrate it somehow into objective C, but I don’t understand how to integrate it with the array of objects without using NSValue thousands times.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help with advise on what direction should I look at? Maybe there is some library available that can be easily used in Objective C with group of objects stored in arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an answer to you question about integrating physics calculations in C with your current Objective-C class. If you have a fragment of C code in your `.m` file which may look like

```
static CGPoint point[MAX_OBJ];
static int n_points = 0;
```

with a corresponding function in plain C as you suggested for simulating physical interactions that acts on `point` to update object positions, as in

```
void tick_world() {
    for (int k = 0; k < n_points; k ++) {
        float speed = sqrtf((point[k].x*point[k].x) + (point[k].y*point[k].y));
        ...
    }
}
```

then, your Objective-C class `Moving` for the moving object could contain a pointer to a particular `CGPoint` in `point` that you would define in the interface (probably the corresponding `*.h` file):

```
@interface Moving : NSObject {
    ...
    CGPoint *pos;
}
```

When handling the `init` message, you can then grab and initialize the next available element in `point`. If your objects persist throughout run time, this could be done very simply simply by

```
@implementation 
...   
-(id)initAtX:(float)x0 Y:(float)y0 {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (n_points == MAX_OBJ) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }
        pos = point + n_points ++;
        pos->x = x0;
        pos->y = y0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

If your `Moving` objects do *not* persist, you might want to think of a smart way to recycle slots after destruction. For example, you could initialize all `x` of `point` with `NAN`, and use this as a way to locate a free slot. In your `dealloc`, you would then `pos->x = NAN`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Learn how to use Instruments. Any performance optimisation is totally pointless unless you *measure* speed before and after your changes. An array of 1000 objects is nothing, so you might be worrying about nothing. Or slowdowns are in a totally different place. Use Instruments.
2. x * x is a multiplication. powf (x, 2.0) is an expensive function call that probably takes anywhere between 20 and 100 times longer.
3. GLKVector2 is a primitive (it is a union). Trying to stash it into an NSValue is totally pointless and wastes probably 100 times more time than just storing it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to clarify, 1) Number of calculation cycles is not equal to number of objects in one array. There are about 100,000 calculations like sqrtf(x*x+b*b)*c To measure speed I used NSTimer. What instrument would you recommend? 2) x*x gave insignificantly better result, but I'm afraid, sqrtf is much more time consuming rather than powf(x,2). 3) Direct storing of GLKVector2 didn't work when the object with GLKVector2 as a property has been added into array. How exactly would you store GLKVector2 directly?

Comment: One more thing, when I replaced = sqrtf(x*x+y*y) with = 0, (which has no physical meaning) the 'speed' of the calculations increased so that I found that these particular operations take up about 70% of time.

Comment: It seems you have a property with a type of NSValue*. Change the type of that property to GLKVector2. "Time Profiler" should help you. For quick measurements, I use just [NSDate date] which has sub-microsecond precision.

Comment: You can't put GLKVector2 elements into an NSArray. But you can easily put 1000 GLKVector2 elements into an array "GLKVector2* array = malloc (1000 * sizeof (*array))". No method calls needed to access anything.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're up against a couple common problems: 1) fast math in a high-level language, and 2) a meta-problem: whether to get the benefit of others' work (OpenGL, [and several ideas listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935075/high-performance-math-library-for-vector-and-matrix-calculations)) in exchange for a steep learning curve as the developer.

Especially for this subject matter, I think the trade is pretty good in favor of using a library.  For many (e.g. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)), most of the learning curve is about integration of Objective C and C++, which you can quickly put behind you.

(As an aside, often times, computing the *square of the distance* between objects is sufficient for making comparisons.  If that works in your app, you can save cycles by replacing  `distance(a,b)` with `distnaceSquared(a,b)`